# Definite Clause Grammars, how to check if a string is a char?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

It seems good to me, but it always gives false... and i can't get why.

```
letter(X) --> [C], {"a"=<C, C=<"z", name(X,[C])}.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to ensure that your grammar gets chars right from the beginning. In that situation, you would not need to use `name/2` (or rather `char_code/2`) for conversion.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

letter(C) --> [C], { atom_length(C,1), a @=< C, C @=< z }.
```

This should work in any system.  In SWI, there is also `char_type/2`:

```
letter(C) --> [C], { atom_length(C,1), char_type(C, lower) }.
```

This will accept also further lower case characters apart from a..z like umlauts.

Note the goal `atom_length(C,1)` which ensures that there are only characters. Otherwise, `letter//1` would also succeed for other terms.